# Neo4j - individual properties, or embedded in JSON? (ROR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, neo4j

I want to know which is more efficient in terms of speed and property limitations of Neo4j.. (I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.2 and REST)

I'm wondering whether I should be storing node properties in a single property, much like a database table, or storing most/all for a node in a single node property but in JSON format.

Right now in a test system I have 1000 nodes with a total of 10000 properties.. Obviously the number of properties is going to skyrocket as more features and new node types are added to my system.

So I was considering storing all the non-searchable properties for a node in an embedded JSON structure.. Except this seems like it will put more burden on the web servers, having to parse the JSON after retrieving it, etc.  (I'm going to use a single property field with JSON for activity feed nodes, but I'm addressing things like photo nodes, profile nodes etc).

Any advice here?  Keep things in separate properties?  A hybrid of JSON and individual properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your goal by storing things in JSON? Do you think you'll hit the 67B limit (which will be going up in 2.1 in a few months to something much larger)?

From a low level store standpoint, there isn't much difference between storing a long string and storing many shorter properties. The main thing you're doing is preventing yourself from using those fields in a query.

Also, if you're using REST, you're going to have to do JSON parsing anyway, so it's not like you're going to completely avoid that.

Comment: In theory, this system could hit 67 billion nodes.. in theory.. The reality is that it probably will never near that amount.. But I just want to see a theory proven out either!! lol..

Comment: I'm using the Neography GEM, which is a wrapper for the REST calls, so the parsing of JSON is being handled by that GEM..  But I agree re using the fields in a query, especially ones that could be used to filter or sort results..